# PHP library to export MySQL structure and data as SQL to file, portable for WAMP/LAMP without command line access

Tags: php, mysql, sql, export

I have not found a library that handles exporting data and structure to SQL. - there are a number of snippets and so on for data only. Exporting structure seems quite a bit more complicated. It must be able to do this without command-line access.

Many of the descriptions I've found online are quite old, so perhaps MySQL has new features that handle this? Or perhaps there are now libraries which do this? (Or perhaps PHPMyAdmin has a self-contained class or set of functions I could hijack?)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: [**Sypex Dumper**](http://sypex.net/en/products/dumper/downloads/)

I used it for a long time with Joomla on XAMPP, very light weight and functional.

You can simply use it standalone or integrate to your application.

Answer (score 0):

This class suited my needs

https://github.com/2createStudio/shuttle-export

You can see several examples in the documentation. The only flaw is that this class don't have the force download option (it always generate the file in disk). I was willing to make a pull request, but there's one push request dating from 6 months ago and the mantainer didn't give a dam.